# Column renumbering Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe like:

```
>>> df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID" ])
>>> df_test["DATE"] = [ '2001-02-01', '2001-03-01', '2001-02-15', '2001-03-15', '2001-02-15', '2001-03-30']
>>> df_test['ID'] = [1,2,3,1,5,4]
>>> df_test
    ID        DATE
0   1  2001-02-01
1   2  2001-03-01
2   3  2001-02-15
3   1  2001-03-15
4   5  2001-02-15
5   4  2001-03-30
```

I would like to reorder the ID columns as follow:

```
>>> df_test
    ID        DATE
0   1  2001-02-01
1   1  2001-03-01
2   1  2001-02-15
3   1  2001-03-15
4   4  2001-02-15
5   4  2001-03-30
```

basically each time there is an ID smaller than the previous one fill back the precedent values with the small ID to keep monotony.
I am trying with the following:

```
df_test.ID.lt(df_test.ID.shift())
```

that gives me the change point in monotony:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

But I don't know how to move forward.
I would appreciate any idea

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the logic behind where the ID should change? Why was it changed from 1 to 4 on index=4?

Comment: The ID identify a progress status 1 (begin) to 5 (end). If the process works fine the change is ideally linear 1,2,3,4,5. But when the status move from 4 (ongoing) back to 1 (begin again) I need to assume that the process was always in a begin status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Not very elegant, but apparently works (you need to debug this on a real data). Note that loop is important here, because every iteration should operate on the current data, not on the initial one.

```
prev_max = 0
for i in range(1, 6):
    cur_max = df_test[df_test.ID == i].index.max()
    if pd.notnull(cur_max):
        df_test.loc[prev_max:cur_max, 'ID'] = i
        prev_max = cur_max + 1
```

Comment: Thanks but the last line throws an error because of different types (multiindex vs int). I maybe fixed with that but looks a bit dirty:  df.index[np.where(df.index.levels[1]==cur_max[1])[0][0]+1]

Comment: @user2320577 but your dataframe doesn't seem to contain multiindex. Is it defined correctly in the question?

Comment: you're right, my bad. I used you solution on a multiindex DF and I had to adapt it a bit. Thank you